# Does being able to remember conscious experience mean consciousness cannot be an epiphenomenon?

Tags: consciousness

It has been proposed (or maybe just speculated) by a number of philosophers and scientists, including Richard Dawkins, that consciousness might be an *epiphenomenon*, but I think this cannot be the case.

According to [Merriam-Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphenomenon), an epiphenomenon is "a secondary mental phenomenon that is caused by and accompanies a physical phenomenon but has no causal influence itself". So, this would imply that if it is only an epiphenomenon, then consciousness can have no effect that outlasts itself.

But, if we look at what we can remember, it is surely (mostly) the memory of conscious experience. We can actually remember *being conscious*. It would seem impossible for us to remember being conscious if consciousness has no causal effect. Leaving a memory in the brain, however tenuous or imperfect, is certainly an effect and if it is a memory of being conscious then surely consciousness must in some way have caused it?

A counter-argument might be that the experience of consciousness arises from certain sub-conscious stimuli in the brain, and it is the sub-conscious stimuli that are recorded in memory, and can be replayed. But that still would not explain how we can recall the actual experience of being conscious.

So, we would need to take the counter argument further: we might say that having recorded the sub-conscious stimuli, a memory of the conscious experience could be reconstructed from this recording, playing back, as it were, those subconscious stimuli to generate a *psuedo*-memory of having been conscious. But I can't see how this could be possible, as playing back the subconscious stimuli would only *re-create* the experience of being conscious - we would not then recall the experience as a memory of the experience in the past, we would instead simply re-experience the whole experience as if we were going through it again.

Any attempt to define a process which can somehow create the memory of being conscious without having recorded the the actual experience itself seems impossible. Which leads to the conclusion it is the experience of consciousness which is being recorded. So, that must mean that consciousness *does* have some causal effect and cannot be an epiphenomenon.

**2019 01 09 - Further exposition of the question, in response to @Conifold's comments**

As I understand it @Conifold's - please correct me if I am wrong - position is: 1) Even if consciousness is an epiphenomenon, it would be possible to form a memory of being conscious. Therefore, being able to remember being conscious does not rule out the proposition that consciousness is an epiphenomenon.

I am going to address only the first part, the problem of forming a *memory of the epiphenomenon of consciousness*. In one of your comments below is an example of the memory of a reflection in a mirror: *One can have a memory of the reflection in the mirror caused by that reflection*. I don't think this addresses the question - my memory of an image I have seen in a mirror is not the same thing as my memory of the *conscious experience of seeing an image in a mirror*. It is the *memory of having had the conscious experience* that I am trying to pin down. Also, I am not convinced that the reflection in a mirror is a helpful parallel anyway, at least not in this context. A reflection can certainly have causal effects, not the least of which is to cause the perception by us of an illusion of space beyond the surface of the mirror. But that illusion is within the brain, it is not a property of the mirror nor the reflected light. The fact that we perceive space beyond the mirror results from the stimulus of the light (which has interacted with the physical properties of the mirror and followed the mathematical rules of reflection) generating signals from my eye that get integrated into an image in my brain.

When referring to consciousness as an epiphenomenon, my understanding is that this idea arises from our inability to detect consciousness having an influence on any decision-making in the brain or having control over physical actions of the body. At least, from my admittedly rather limited reading of the various discussions in which this point has been made, I understand this to be the key issue: can consciousness get involved in decisions to take physical action and contribute to improved survival chances, which could then explain its own evolution? If not, then we could abolish consciousness and still all go about our lives in exactly the same way, but without having any conscious experience of any of it.

I raised the original question because I think it's very likely (and, I hope, widely accepted) that memories play a part in survival. For example, the memory of being in a life-threatening situation could help me to avoid getting into that situation again, and thereby help me to survive. If memory has any purpose at all, that seems like a good one. Therefore, I surmised, if we can show that consciousness *does* have an effect on memory, then it is quite possible that consciousness could help survival, albeit indirectly. Clearly there would be many other implications, but those are beyond the scope of the question.

That's why I have focused on the question of whether can we tell if consciousness has an effect on memory. My proposition is: if it is possible to remember the *experience of being conscious*, then the only possible source of the memory is the conscious experience itself. It is impossible for any other function of the brain to generate a memory of the experience of being conscious, because no other function of the brain has access to conscious experience to be able to create a memory of what it feels like. If you say there could be another function of the brain that "watches" conscious experience in some way, and records what it "sees" so that the experience can be played back, then my response would be that you are simply interposing a layer of the mechanism of memory (which must exist in some form anyway), and any such mechanism does not detract from the point that it is the conscious experience which has caused the memory. That memory is a change in the state of the brain, and it may have an effect, however slight, on subsequent actions. That tenuous connection, however slight, torpedoes the epiphenomenon idea.

Comment: Being an epiphenomenon does not mean not being "actual". It only means that it has no causal power to effect the consequences (physical, in this case). If "consciousness" necessarily accompanies some brain states then reproducing the states would reproduce the "consciousness", in all of its "actuality". Just as if you reproduce the same setup in front of a mirror you'll see the same reflection in the mirror, its epiphenomenality notwithstanding.

Comment: @Conifold - thanks for your comment - but doesn't that have the problem that reproducing the brain states would just recreate the conscious experience again, not the memory of having previously been conscious? I can't see how you can remember a conscious experience without that conscious experience having caused the memory. And, if it is an epiphenomenon, then no part of the brain could "know" what consciousness feels like in order to create a memory of it.

Comment: One can have a memory of the reflection in the mirror caused by that reflection. But it is still epiphenomenal regarding what happens in front of the mirror. Moreover, when "conscious experience" is reproduced the reproduction may well come with a phenomenal marker of it being a reproduction. Memory *is* a reproduction, whether it is a reproduction of "conscious experience", or just a reproduction accompanied by attendant "conscious experience", is a distinction without a difference as far as phenomenology is concerned.

Comment: Thank you @Conifold again for your comments. I am not really well-enough versed in some of the terminology you are using, so I will need to do a bit more research. It may take me some time to try to understand your points and then perhaps to develop my argument further in response.

Comment: In simpler terms, whether our conscious experience is recreated from the original experience, or only the brain state is recreated, and accompanied by the same experience, we can not tell from the experiencing itself. So it can be epiphenomenal. It can also be epiphenomenal in the sense of not affecting brain states at the time of the experiencing, but causally active enough to create a trace in memory.

Comment: If it is *causally active enough to create a trace in memory* then, surely, it is not an epiphenomenon, by definition? I am still researching / drafting my more detailed argument. Maybe a day or two . . .

Comment: "Epiphenomenal" in the mind-body problem usually means that brain states are causally complete in themselves, i.e. affected by prior brain states and not "conscious experiences". It would make no difference to their epiphenomenality if they can leave memory traces in some non-brain repository. But this is mostly academic, there is no need for them to leave memory traces either for brains to produce identical "remembered" experiences.

Comment: Hmmm . . . I am definitely missing something here. "*there is no need for them to leave memory traces either for brains to produce identical "remembered" experiences*" - The memory of an experience is not a recreation of the experience from raw inputs. It is a memory of *the experience itself*. It is the experience that has been remembered, and is being recalled. To suggest that all (or a lot of) the sensory input of the experience is somehow separately recorded and then used to create a completely new representation of the experience, somehow at one remove, seems unnecessary,

Comment: ..and.. Where did a "*non-brain repository*" suddenly appear from? That seems like a new invention to get round the objection. If I understand correctly, the suggestion is that there would be some kind of *special non-brain memory that is accessible to consciousness but not to the brain*. I am reaching for Occam's razor.

Comment: If the "experience itself" is epiphenomenal then there is no memory "of it", only a record of brain state which is then reproduced along with the halo of "experience". Occam's razor goes against you here, as *you* need a "non-brain repository" to store "the experience itself". What is the point of storing it in the brain which already has a record of its own states?

Comment: It seems I haven't expressed myself very clearly. I am ruling out a non-brain memory, and proposing that consciousness *can* record a memory in the brain, which could be accessible to decision-making processes. My proposition is that if this is true, then the idea that the conscious experience is epiphenomenal is wrong.

Comment: Ooops. I have got a message that I should avoid discussions in comments. Pity, this was fun. Thank you very much for your input and help, @Conifold

Comment: But you wanted more than a proposition, rather an *argument* against the epiphenomenality. So what is the argument that the halo imprints itself on the brain rather than that the state itself, which it surrounds, gets imprinted? Since reproduction of the state reproduces the halo memory can provide no evidence one way or the other. Don't worry about the message, moderators will move this discussion into chat when it plays out.

Comment: I am unable to understand how anyone could think consciousness has no causal influence. Form here the idea appears to fly in the face of every scrap of evidence. Ryle speaks of the 'steam from a steam-train' and forgets that without the steam there is no train. .

Comment: See also here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/54474/how-do-epiphenomenalists-make-sense-of-discussions-about-qualia

Comment: To be honest, I've never had much idea why anyone would endorse epiphenomenalism except because they feel forced to by the logic of their other beliefs. It seems to me that if our conscious experience is epiphenomal we would have no beliefs at all about conscious experience, never mind memories of it.

Comment: @PeterJ - Well, I agree that it goes right against our instincts simply to discard consciousness, but it seems the evidence from *some* experiments has appeared to show that decisions to act are not consciously made, they bubble up from somewhere sub-conscious. Therefore, some have been rather eager to conclude, mere instincts are wrong (a very tempting claim in philosophy) and consciousness just happens as a by-product, playing no part in anything. I guess it's rather fun as a philosophical game, but otherwise, I think, it's not useful.

Comment: @SteveLovell Isn't it great to consider all those learned papers about ephiphenominalism having been written by *bodies with brains* but without any contribution at all from any *conscious thought* by those *highly educated streams of consciousness* who might, you would think, claim to have had some part in their production. They would have to concede that they were merely spectators in the process :)

Comment: Mind you, I have to admit, if I were an unappreciated and over-worked body-brain churning out lengthy and carefully argued academic papers, I would do everything I could to make sure that the uppity self-important *consciousness* that keeps appearing from nowhere and trying to take credit for everything is brought down a peg or two. LOL

Comment: @JohnRC - We seem to share a view. The experiments by Libet are not conclusive and have received other interpretations. Great point about the difficulty of writing about consciousness without admitting it is causal. Not an obviously sensible argument .It only takes a naive child to point out the Emperor has no clothes.

Comment: For interest: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/69660/33787

Answer (score 0):

Since the laying down of memory is a physical process in the brain, then consciousness appears to have a physical effect. Moreover, the memory may later trigger other physical effects in the outside world through conscious action. As regards Dawkins, he seems to be specifically concerned with the evolution of consciousness in humans and whether it has a selective advantage. My panpsychist view is that consciousness is already there at a fundamental, universal level. In that view, consciousness is definitely not an epiphenomenon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Well, I am not a panpsychist myself, and it seems to me the concept of panpsychism is not needed to provide support for the argument, which is from prinicple. I use the definition of "epiphenomenon" itself to show that conciousness must be excluded from membership of the club. In fact, I think you might need to rely on the claim that consciousness is not an epiphenomenon as a _precondition_ of proposing panpsychism, not as something you can deduce from it. Panpsychism is a puzzle to me but I guess that;s a subject for a different thread :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just done some more work on this, having raised the question some time ago. Now I think I have something of an answer, and think my original conclusion was wrong.

My assertion in the question that an epiphenomenon cannot have **any** causal effects is not quite right. The point about an epiphenomenon is that it does not have any causal effect on the observed events that lead to or accompany its occurrence. So the point is that if you *think you have decided consciously* to do something, the epiphenominalist would claim that, in fact, you have not so decided. The conscious experience of having made a decision is in fact an illusion, the decision having been made prior to or in parallel with the conscious experience, not as part of it.

There is nothing to debar the conscious experience from having effects, such as the process of recording the experience itself in memory in some way, so that the experience can later be recalled as part of a new conscious experience.

Comment: Under epiphenomenalism mind cannot have any functional effect, you memory recording effects as commonly understood seem very functional...

Comment: Hmmm yes good point. Maybe I was right first time round, then?

Comment: The answer hinges on how you honestly view your 4 years of consciousness effort about above original post, is it no functional effect or actual worse tangible effect?…

Answer (score 0):

Consciousness does a very large number of functions for us.  Here is a podcast series that details many of these functions:  https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/theory-knowledge/202012/untangling-the-world-knot-consciousness https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTJe1xFfoxrAIyl5r1dB4La6zzMfUZVyd

If consciousness does ANY functions then it is not epiphenomenal.  Causing memory traces is an excellent example of one of the functions that consciousness serves as a causal driver for.  You could also pull out dozens of other functional examples from the psychological study of consciousness.

Answer (score 0):

Remembering itself is a conscious experience, so the claim 'consciousness is epiphenomenal' is not disproven by remembering, because remembering may also be epiphonemonal.

There are things you can point to that reasonably disprove the epiphenomenal conception of consciousness, but I wouldn't considering "remembering" to be one of them. I don't think consciousness or remembering ARE epiphenomenal, for the record.